# Botones editar y borrar dentro de una tabla html usando php

Tags: php, html

estoy un poco perdido con una cosa que estoy intentando hacer ya que soy bastante nuevo con PHP, a ver si me explico bien... Tengo una tabla HTML que me muestra ciertos campos de mi BD y en dicha tabla hay 2 columnas con botones de editar y borrar usando imágenes, lo que quiero conseguir es que esos botones hagan sus funciones con los datos de cada fila por separado, no sé si me he explicado bien. Si me podéis echar una mano se agradecería bastante ya que mi profesor no me ha servido de mucha ayuda jajaja

Si necesitáis ver el código no hay problema, todo me funciona menos el tema botones que no sé ni por donde cogerlo sinceramente.

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 include("../conexion.php");
?>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
  <head>
      <title>Editar parte de incidencia</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../princip_admin.css">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="../favicon.png">
  </head>
  <body>
        <div id="cabecera">
            <div id="logo">
                <img id="logo_img" src="../Imagenes/logo.png">
        </div>
            <div id="cerrar">
                <a class="cerrar" href="../cerrar_sesion.php"><img id="cerrar_img" src="../Imagenes/cerrar.png"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="titulo">
                <h1>Editar parte de incidencia</h1>
        </div>
            <form method="POST" action="buscador.php">
                <input type="text" name="cpalabra" id="buscador"/> 
                <input type="submit" value="Buscar" />
            </form>
            
           <table id="tab_edit">
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>Alumno</th>
                    <th>Grupo</th>
                    <th>Tipo</th>
                    <th><img id="img_tab_edit" src="../Imagenes/editar.png"/></th>
                    <th><img id="img_tab_edit" src="../Imagenes/borrar.png"/></th>
                    <th><img id="img_tab_edit" src="../Imagenes/visualizacion.jpg"/></th>
                </tr>
     <?php
             
             $query = "SELECT ID_parte, Alumnos, Grupo, Tipos FROM partes";
             $result = mysqli_query($_SESSION['conexion'],$query) or die( mysqli_error($_SESSION['conexion']));
             
             while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
             
                  echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>".$row["0"]."</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$row["1"]."</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$row["2"]."</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$row["3"]."</td>";
                  echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=".$row["0"]."'></a><img id='img_tab_edit' src='../Imagenes/borrar.png'/></td>";
              echo "</tr>";
             }
        ?>
            
           </table>
```

Aquí el archivo para el botón de borrar, el error mostrado es en la línea donde creo $borrado.

```html
<?php
 session_start();
 include("../conexion.php");
 
 $id=$_GET['id']
 $borrado = "DELETE FROM partes WHERE ID_parte = $id";
 
 if (mysqli_query($_SESSION['conexion'],$borrado)) {
   mysqli_close($_SESSION['conexion']);
   exit;
 } else {
   echo "Error al borrar campo seleccionado.";
 }
?>
```

Comment: Mustra el codigo, seria de ayuda.

Comment: En primer lugar en necesario ver el código para ayudarte . pero igual para que tus botones funcionen es necesario crear una función que elimine el dato y que sea llamada por get o post usando un from .

Comment: Voy a añadir el código que tengo.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que estás cometiendo un error de digitación, es decir, veo que tienes la imagen fuera de la etiqueta `<a>`, por lo demás, el código se ve bien. Intenta así:

```
echo "<td><a href='delete.php?id=".$row["0"]."'><img id='img_tab_edit' src='../Imagenes/borrar.png'/></a></td>";
```

Comment: Es verdad, no me había fijado, muchas gracias! Después lo probaré y dejaré por aquí el resultado. Otra pregunta que tengo es, ¿si quisiera hacer un botón de la misma forma pero para editar la información de la tabla, sería exactamente igual pero utilizando un update en la query en vez de delete no?

Comment: Exáctamente, ya como logras pasar y obtener `$row["0"]`, que es el Id, entonces sería el mismo procedimiento. Ya prácticamente lo tienes resuelto.

Comment: El error que me sale ahora es el siguiente: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$borrar' (T_VARIABLE) in E:\XAMPP\App\Xampp\htdocs\Proyecto\Editar_parte\delete.php on line 6

Comment: Cómo estás recibiendo la variable en el PHP? Muesetra por favor como la estás recibiendo para mirar el error que muestras.

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado, era error mío porque me faltaba ; después de recibir la variable, después lo compruebo y os aviso.

Comment: Ok @JamieWright, espero lo hayas logrado y espero haberte ayudado en algo.